# Tooltip On Top of Module

Tags: joomla-4, joomla-4.1

I updated joomla to J4.1.4 and now i am getting module information top right of all the modules.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for joining and posting your question, Richard.  Please take our [tour].  Do you mean "top left"?  I don't see any tooltips.

Comment: yes sorry top left

Comment: <div role="tooltip" id="tip-152">Edit Module<br>mainSlider<br>Position: banner</div>

Comment: using the debugging console of firefox

Comment: <div style="border: 0px !important;"> <a class="btn btn-link jmodedit" href="https://www.enlo.co.uk/index.php?option=com_config&view=modules&id=152&Itemid=101&return=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZW5sb3ViYXIuY28udWsv" target="_self" aria-describedby="tip-152">
 <span class="icon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="visually-hidden">Edit</span></a>
 <div role="tooltip" id="tip-152">Edit Module<br>mainSlider<br>Position: banner</div>
    <div id="djslider-loader152" class="djslider-loader djslider-loader-default" data-animation='{"auto":"1","looponce":"0","transition":"easeInOutExpo","css3transitio

Comment: This issue started when I updated to Joomla 4.1.4 this issue didn't exist before

Comment: I believe you.  Please add all relevant details to your question as an [edit].  You are permitted to make unlimited edits to your question.  Questions allow much better formatting functionality than comments.  After transferring all details to your question, please delete your comments to keep the page tidy.

Answer (score 2):

The tooltips are meant to appear when logged in with a user authorized to edit modules and frontend editing is enabled. If you are not logged in, you should check permission settings, there could be some serious misconfiguration.

As to why the tooltips appear this way is because your template has no styling applied to them. Unfortunately, Joomla does not provide styling library for common utilities like tooltips. You have to inspect the stylesheets of core templates to figure things out. Instead of targeting a class, core templates apply tooltip styling to all elements with `role="tooltip"` attribute. This, for example, is the CSS code used in Cassiopeia template:

```
[role=tooltip]:not(.show) {
  right: 5em;
  z-index: 1070;
  display: none;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  color: black;
  text-align: start;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #6d757e;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
[role=tooltip]:not(.show)[id^=editarticle-] {
  right: auto;
  -webkit-margin-start: -10em;
          margin-inline-start: -10em;
}
[role=tooltip]:not(.show)[id^=editcontact-] {
  right: auto;
  -webkit-margin-start: -10em;
          margin-inline-start: -10em;
}
[role=tooltip]:not(.show)[id^=id-skip-] {
  right: auto;
}

:focus + [role=tooltip],
:hover + [role=tooltip] {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

.filter-search-bar__description {
  bottom: 100%;
}
```

And, yes, even `.filter-search-bar__description` rule is related to tooltips. 3rd party extensions might need additional workarounds to make tooltips work properly.

Comment: The `right: 5em;` in `[role=tooltip]:not(.show)` doesn't make that much sense in my opinion. If you delete it, the tooltip is always displayed at the link location and not somewhere on the website.

Comment: @Gratia-Mira this example was copied straight from Joomla. If you think the code can be improved, submit a pull request in its repository.