# How can I display edit icon for articles?

Tags: templates, joomla-4.1

I have created a Joomla 4.1.5 template based on Cassiopeia but heavily customised. Everything works fine but instead of a front-end Edit icon on the right above articles (for a user with edit permissions) it displays hyperlink text "Edit Published Article" on the left. In Cassiopeia it displays the expected icon, so it seems I may have removed the relevant code. I can edit the article using the hyperlink but would prefer to have the Edit icon.

I can't find any information about where this icon is generated.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing tooltip styling. As mentioned in [this answer](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/32209/12652), you need to add styling for all elements with `role="tooltip"` attribute. There is no generic CSS library included so you'll have to write your own or copy-paste from core templates.

Comment: Many thanks. I'll follow through on that.